# Can't any data from a checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using [Carbon Design System](http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=Checkbox&selectedStory=checked&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) and the checkbox component from it. With a `console.log` all I get is `true` when the checkbox is checked and `false` when it's not.

I am doing this:

```
const onChange = event => {
  console.log(event);
};
```

And this on the render method:

```
{CheckboxItems(t).map(item => (
  <ToolbarOption key={item.id}>
    <Checkbox key={item.id} id={item.id} labelText={item.labelText} value= 
    {item.value} onChange={onChange} />
  </ToolbarOption>
))}
```

If you see the URL I posted above, there is a tab named `Action Logger` where you can see the data. But I can't get that same log on my app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=Checkbox&selectedStory=checked&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel), the `onChange` function provides three props being in the order: `value id event`

So to get the same output as the action logger, you have to refractor the `onChange` function to:

```
onChange = (value, id, event) => {
  console.log({value, id, event})
}
```